# Not separator at the last of foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm stuck; I want to not have the "-" separator on my last item! How can I do that? I know I'm supposed to use count, but I don't know how to go further.

```
$report = array();
$job = null; //on met la variable a zero
$i = null;


//On extrait les valeurs dans un nouveau tableau à l'aide d'une boucle :

foreach ($values_collaborateurs as $key_collab => $row_collab)//id collab prendra chaque valeur du tableau
{
    //ici ne pas mettre de report[key_collab]

    //exit(var_dump($values_collaborateurs));
    $report[] = $row_collab; // la valeur de id collab = indice collab

        //On re extrait les valeurs: boucle du table mission:
        //pour chaque élément de $values_missions => id-mission
        foreach($values_missions as $key_mission => $row_mission)
        {

            //ici ne pas mettre de report[key_missions]
            // ici la condition de recherche
            if ($row_collab[0] == $row_mission[1])
            {
                $job .= $row_mission[2]." - ";// .= concatenation pr dire s'ajoute a row mission la valeur de job
            // rempli le job par des valeurs

            }

          }

        $report[$key_collab][] = $job;  //$report = table qui contient chq valeur des key collab, et tout ça tu le stock ds $job

        $i = null;
        $job = null; //stop - remet le cycle job a zero pour recommencer a null

}

        print_r("<pre>\n");
        print_r($report);
        print_r("<pre>\n");
        printf("<br>\n");//passage a la ligne
?>
```

Comment: I think it's better to store it as array then `implode()` it, rather than concat then trimming

Answer (score 0):

U can delete last two chars after foreach is completed using strlen...
        foreach($values_missions as $key_mission => $row_mission)
        {

```
        //ici ne pas mettre de report[key_missions]
        // ici la condition de recherche
        if ($row_collab[0] == $row_mission[1])
        {
            $job .= $row_mission[2]." - ";// .= concatenation pr dire s'ajoute a row mission la valeur de job
        // rempli le job par des valeurs

        }

      }
      $job = substr($job,0,strlen($job)-2);
```

Other solution is:

```
 $jobs[] = $row_mission[2]; // instead of: $job .= $row_mission[2] . " - ";
```

and after foreach will ended:

```
 $job = implode(" - ", $jobs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to determine the total number of items and compare it with a counter (`$current_mission`) that you increment each iteration step.

Then you can append the separator only if the current item is not the last one:

```
$current_mission = 1;
$total_missions = count($values_missions);

foreach($values_missions as $key_mission => $row_mission)
{
    //ici ne pas mettre de report[key_missions]
    // ici la condition de recherche
    if ($row_collab[0] == $row_mission[1])
    {
        $job .= $row_mission[2];// .= concatenation pr dire s'ajoute a row mission la valeur de job

        if ($current_mission < $total_missions) {
            $job .= ' - ';
        }
        // rempli le job par des valeurs
    }

    ++$current_mission;
}
```

An alternative is to build an array of strings and use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score -1):

I highly suggest to not build an array and then use `implode`, as it's too much overhead for both CPU and memory. If you go for `substr($job,0,strlen($job)-2);` you are better off with `substr($job, 0, -3);`, which does exactly the same.

If it's easier to read for you, you can do `$job .= ' - ' . $row_mission[2];` and then `substr($job, 3);`.

On a side note, your code looks buggy:

You use `$report[] = $row_collab;`, and later `$report[$key_collab][]`, which means you are using `$report`both as un-indexed array and associative array. That your data looks right might just be a coincidence, because if `$key_collab`and `$row_collab` have the same value, they overwrite each other.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be nice and fair, we are here to help, right?